# How to wait for completion of sheet after invoking beginSheet:completionHandler:

Tags: xcode, cocoa

My code results in the sheet appearing and functioning properly but the invoker receives control back (as per Apple definition) before the sheet ends itself with endSheet.

How can I get the invoker to wait for the return from the end of the sheet processing, so the resultValue is updated.

Invoker:

```
[self.window beginSheet: sheetController.window
    completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
        resultValue = returnCode;
    }
];
...
```

Sheet:

```
...
[self.window.sheetParent endSheet:self.window returnCode:false];
```

Comment: Don't wait. There is always a way to handle the asynchronous bahavior.

Comment: @vadian So how would you handle this situation where there's nothing else to do but you've been given control to do something?

Comment: If you are talking about a modal sheet, you can use a class extension that does `beginSheetModalForWindow` with `stopModalWithCode` in the completionHandler, followed by `runModalForWindow` (I don't use Obj-C/Swift for an example).

Comment: @red_menace  I originally made the app work using `beginSheet:ModalForWindow` etc., but it's now deprecated and I'm trying to implement Apple's suggested replacement, somehow, as above, but the documentation isn't thorough nor clear. And yes, I want modal type behavior for the sheet.

Comment: I'm wondering if I've improperly used or placed the `endSheet:' invocation? Thanks.

Comment: Just put whatever code is represented by `...` in your first snippet into the completion handler.

Comment: @Ken Thomases  That's interesting, but what follows (`...`) is the entire rest of the code, a couple thousand lines of it, and worse: this modal sheet invocation is not always part of the user's process. :) It's an occasional event,

Comment: Well, that code needs to be split up regardless. If you separate things out into appropriately-focused methods or functions, it will be simple to invoke it in the right places (once in a code path where the sheet is used, once in a code path where it isn't).

Comment: Just wire some actions or after task is finished (delegate call) use:  [[self window] endSheet:[self progressWindow]];

Answer (score 2):

I thought the new `beginSheet:` was meant to do the whole linkage, but that isn't the case. All it does is put up the sheet window. The passage and return of control remains as it was. So the following code works:

Invoker:

```
[self.window beginSheet: sheetController.window
    completionHandler:nil
];
returnCodeValue = [NSApp runModalForWindow:sheetController.window];
    // Sheet is active until stopModalWithCode issued.
[NSApp endSheet: sheetController.window];
[sheetController.window orderOut:self];
```

Sheet:

```
[NSApp stopModalWithCode:whatever];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're most of the way there. The return code should be type NSModalResponse (ObjC) or NSApplication.ModalResponse (Swift). I've also found that you need to uncheck 'Visible at Launch'. Otherwise it won't launch as modal.

[image: Window options]

Comment: Okay, yes, it is setup accordingly to no avail. But the problem seems to exist in the architecture of the environment, where an asynchronous process (the modal sheet) can be initiated apparently without any way to suspend the invoker until the modal's completion. A lack of recognition of such a frequently normal situation would exhibit a profound misunderstanding of the management required in an asynchronous, event-driven environment. So, unless there exists some way to resolve this issue provided by Apple's engineers, they would seem incompetent. I can't believe that, so where's the solution?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your problem now. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you think the code should block at the point of calling beginSheet. Since this is done on the main thread, that would mean that the entire interface would block since all UI events and related code happens on the main thread. As was mentioned in the comments above, you need to restructure your code so that, rather than procedurally going through all the steps in order, your system responds to the user's actions. You'll need to break up your code into focused functions that can be called from the completionHandler.

Comment: You are close to the truth. I found the solution, in the previous version of the code. See my own answer below.

Comment: It does accomplish what you were looking for, but there's no category necessary. All the functionality is built into NSAlert.

Answer (score 0):

There was an [NSAlert category from way back](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/desktop-apps/blob/master/macos/ONLYOFFICE/Code/Extensions/NSAlert%2BSynchronousSheet.m) that used the older (deprecated) methods.  I’m not all that great with Objective-C (and worse with Swift), but I’ve been using an updated equivalent for a while in one of my RubyMotion projects.  Hopefully I’ve come close with reversing the code conversions, but basically it fires up a modal event loop with `runModalForWindow:` after calling  `beginSheetModalForWindow;`, and the completionHandler exits with `stopModalWithCode:`

```
// NSAlert+SynchronousSheet.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

/* A category to allow NSAlerts to be run synchronously as sheets. */
@interface NSAlert (SynchronousSheet)

/* Runs the receiver modally as a sheet attached to the specified window.
   Returns a value positionally identifying the button clicked */
-(NSInteger) runModalSheetForWindow:(NSWindow *)aWindow;

/* Same as above, but runs the receiver modally as a sheet attached to the
   main window. */
-(NSInteger) runModalSheet;

@end


// NSAlert+SynchronousSheet.m

#import "NSAlert+SynchronousSheet.h"

@implementation NSAlert (SynchronousSheet)

-(NSInteger) runModalSheetForWindow:(NSWindow *)theWindow {
    // Bring up the sheet and wait until it completes.
    [self beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow
                 completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
        // Get the button pressed - see NSAlert's Button Return Values.
        [NSApp stopModalWithCode:returnCode];
    }];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:self.window]  // fire up the event loop
}

-(NSInteger) runModalSheet {
    return [self runModalSheetForWindow:[NSApp mainWindow]];
}

@end
```

The application will wait for the alert to finish before continuing, with the modal response passed in the result.  I don’t know about blocking a couple of thousand lines of code, but I found it useful when chaining two or three sheets, such as an alert before an open/save panel.